# For inference of Dirichlet Process Mixture, why the expected value $\int h(x)f(x)$ is desired?

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, nonparametric-bayes, dirichlet-process

Why the expected value $\int h(x)f(x)$ is desired for inference in Dirichlet Process Mixture?
What is the intuition for MCMC in Dirichlet Process Mixture?

$f(x)$ is the probability density function, and $h(x)$ is the outcome of the Dirichlet Process Mixture (I am not sure).

This formula is originally from page 40 of [slides](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs3750/lectures/class23.pdf).

Comment: What are $h(x)$ and $f(x)$. Please add details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the expected value ∫h(x)f(x) is desired for inference in Dirichlet Process Mixture?

I assume the author's $h(\cdot)$ is an arbitrary function of $x$. Monte Carlo estimation allows us to take expected values of arbitrary functions, where the expected value is over the posterior distribution $f(\cdot)$ in the above. So slide 40 is saying something very general about Bayesian stats, not particular information about DP models.

> What is the intuition for MCMC in Dirichlet Process Mixture?

The DP mixture model is over the space of all partitions of the data. That's a pretty big/difficult thing to work with. MCMC for DP-mixtures works by moving around between plausible partitions of the dataset.

Inference for DP mixtures is still an active research topic because on big datasets the number of partitions is *vast* meaning finding 'good' ones is hard.

--EDIT: There are multiple Gibbs and other MCMC algorithms for the DP-MM. [Neal 2000](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~rdutta/24.PDF) gives a review as they stood then. For example, Algo 3 from that paper updates the latent class memberships one at a time, using conditional probability given all the other class assignments.--

Checking out [Teh's Dirichlet Process](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/~ywteh/research/npbayes/dp.pdf) entry for the encyclopedia of machine learning might help.

Comment: Thank you. As for as I know, Gibbs sampling is to use some tractable conditional probability to generate a sequence of samples, and then use these samples to estimate some features of the distribution, such as mean and variance. In the [slides](http://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs3750/lectures/class23.pdf), from page 40 to 48, they are taking about inference in Dirichlet process mixture, especially on page 42 (Gibbs sampling), I do not know how make the connection between inference with Gibbs sampling.

Comment: Updated with a link. Feel free to accept if this helps.